# simple join SQL like with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have documents and parameters and I'm trying to build a query to select the documents matching the parameters.

```
document {
_id : ...,
status : ...,
type : ...,
...
}
```

```
parameter {
_id : ...,
parameter : ...,
status : ...,
type : ...,
}
```

I do think SQL it kills me. 
How do I do :

```
select document.* from document,parameter 
  where document.type = parameter.type and document.status = parameter.status
         and parameter.parameter="example"
```

I might not have think is the proper way ex : i don't use the any reference link between both objects, I might but it would be an N to N link and I don't feel like it would be easy to maintain as parameter or document would be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below query :

```
db.document.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "parameter",
           let: { type: "$type", status: "$status" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$parameter",  "example" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$type",  "$$type" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$status", "$$status" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           as: "documentParameterJoined"
         }
    }
])
```

**Document Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e160929627ef782360f69aa"),
    "status" : "mystatus",
    "type" : "whattype"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e160931627ef782360f6abb"),
    "status" : "mystatus1",
    "type" : "whattype1"
}
```

**Parameter Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e16095f627ef782360f6e1d"),
    "parameter" : "example",
    "status" : "mystatus",
    "type" : "whattype"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e16097e627ef782360f70b5"),
    "parameter" : "example",
    "status" : "mystatus1",
    "type" : "whattype1"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e160985627ef782360f7152"),
    "parameter" : "example1",
    "status" : "mystatus",
    "type" : "whatType"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e160a39627ef782360f8027"),
    "parameter" : "example",
    "status" : "mystatus1",
    "type" : "whatType"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e160a42627ef782360f80ec"),
    "parameter" : "example",
    "status" : "mystatus",
    "type" : "whatType1"
}
```

**Result :**

```
 // You don't see docs 3 to 5 as they don't match any filter criteria.
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e160929627ef782360f69aa"),
    "status" : "mystatus",
    "type" : "whattype",
    "documentParameterJoined" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e16095f627ef782360f6e1d"),
            "parameter" : "example",
            "status" : "mystatus",
            "type" : "whattype"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e160931627ef782360f6abb"),
    "status" : "mystatus1",
    "type" : "whattype1",
    "documentParameterJoined" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e16097e627ef782360f70b5"),
            "parameter" : "example",
            "status" : "mystatus1",
            "type" : "whattype1"
        }
    ]
}
```

You don't need to do two db calls, you can use `$lookup` (which is native to mongoDB) with expression to achieve what's needed. Also you can try similar using `mongoose populate` (which is a kind of wrapper to mongoDB `$lookup`)

**Ref :** [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#examples) , [mongoose-populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with this that is buggy, yet I'm still open to suggestion.

```
parameter.find({parameter :"example"}, function(err, parameters){
  var parameters_status;
  var parameters_type;

  if (err) {
    // do error handling
    return;
  }

  parameters_status= parameters.map(function (parameters) { return parameters.status; });
  parameters_type= parameters.map(function (parameters) { return parameters.type; });

  document.find({type: {$in: parameters_type},status : {$in: parameters_status} }, function (err, documents) {
    if (err) {
      // do error handling
      return;
    }

    console.log(documents);
    // do something with the documents
  });
});
```